# How can I crop an image that's currently a dataURL?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, data-uri

I only have access to an image created with .toDataURL. I can't seem to use any canvas methods to recrop it.

I'm trying to copy the dataURL to a second canvas, crop that canvas, then add that new cropped canvas to an existing element (#screenshot).

```
<body>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  <canvas id='canvasCrop'></canvas>
</body>

<script>

  //existing data from an svg-to-canvas screen capture, taken from #canvas element   
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

  //get empty second canvas
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasCrop');
  var myContext = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

  var myImage;
  var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataURL;
      img.onload = () => {
        myContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0,1920,1080,0,0,1920,1080);
        myContext.save();

        //create a new data URL
        myImage = myCanvas.toDataURL();
      };

  //add to existing containers
  var screenshotImg = $("<img></img>");
  screenshotImg.attr("src", myImage);
  screenshotImg.prependTo("#screenshot");

</script>
```

To note: When I send the original "dataURL" to the screenshot element it works fine. As soon as I try to crop the original dataURL it gets corrupted somehow. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `canvas.get(0)` `<canvas>`  elements don't have a `get()` method. Did you build this example off a code that was using jQuery? If so you might want to revise it to work like your actual code. Otherwise if not then that will be your problem, your code is erroring out as it is trying to use a function that doesn't exist

Comment: And you are calling toDataURL before the image is drawn (this will happen asynchronously on the img.onload handler)

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you, good point. Yes i am grabbing that from a jQuery operation, but it is grabbing the correct part of it. I went back and cleaned it up so that the canvas.toDataURL() call is clean, but the issues are the same. For some reason MyImage is not parsing back to an image.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you... how can I make sure that it gets called at the correct moment?

Comment: Move your code inside this onload handler.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks. Tried it but still getting the same result. I've updated the code above to reflect my build. To note that the first "dataURL" variable works perfectly fine when added to <<screenshotImg.attr("src", dataURL);>>at the end. I get a clean, full image. But when I try to reconvert it through the second canvas loop I get a data string in the console, but it's blank when added to the screenshotImg element. I'll keep pounding away at it! Thanks for the direction...

Comment: Move everything that should be called after inside this handler... https://jsfiddle.net/e31cL08h/ You never heard about asynchronicity in programming? JS is full of it, it's a must-know.

Comment: @Kaiido - aaaaa, thanks so much! working now! I totally understand the idea of asynchronicity but have never been able to get a handle on it, it's my most frustrating hurdle every time I code something.  This project is helping get another angle on it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Kaiido if you post as a separate comment I can mark it as attributed to you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

code fixed to reflect @Kaiido comments below.

```
<body>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  <canvas id='canvasCrop' width='1920px' height='1080px'></canvas>
</body>

<script>

  //existing data from an svg-to-canvas screen capture, taken from #canvas element   
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

  //get empty second canvas
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasCrop');
  var myContext = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

  var myImage;
  var img = new Image();
      img.src = dataURL;
      img.onload = () => {
        myContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0,1920,1080,0,0,1920,1080);
        myContext.save();

        //create a new data URL
        myImage = myCanvas.toDataURL();

        //add to existing containers
        var screenshotImg = $("<img></img>");
        screenshotImg.attr("src", myImage);
        screenshotImg.prependTo("#screenshot");
      };

</script>
```